# No exact matches in call to initializer in array (Swift/SwiftUI)

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to display my array in a ForEach with its own properties

I have the following array:

```
[Exercise(name: "Pull-up", reps: 10, time: 45),
Exercise(name: "Push-up", reps: 10, time: 30),
Exercise(name: "Sit-up", reps: 20, time: 60),])
```

And I can display its name but if I use the reps or time property it tells me:

"No exact matches in call to initializer"

```
HStack {
  Text((workout[value] as! Exercise).reps).foregroundColor(.white) <-- error
  Text((workout[value] as! Exercise).name).foregroundColor(.white) <-- works
}
```

Comment: `Text` takes a string. `reps` is an integer. Change it to `Text(String(workout[value] as! Exercise).reps))`

Comment: In addition to @CodeDifferent, `Text("\((workout[value] as! Exercise).reps)")` also works

Comment: Swift doesn't always give the clearest error messages. (Neither does SwiftUI.) It helps to break the statement down into a bunch of smaller statements. First, extract reps into a temporary variable, and then create a Text object with that value. That will point to the fact that it's the `Text(Int)` bit that's failing. (The initializer for Text takes a String, as others have already pointed out.)

Comment: Yeah they could really improve some of the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the `reps` to a `String` like this:

```
         HStack {
           Text(String((workout[value] as! Exercise).reps)).foregroundColor(.white) 
           Text((workout[value] as! Exercise).name).foregroundColor(.white)
         }
```

Comment: Oh man such a basic solution haha it worked thanks